# zeromq - always loses the first message

Tags: php, zeromq

I've been trying to set up a simple "pipeline" with zeromq between my local computer and a remote server.
I tested the script on my local computer and it worked perfectly, but when I tried to use the remote computer as the end (The one with the SOCKET_PULL), I started having problems. The first message sent by any process was always lost.

Th code is simple,

The push (sender.php):

```
<?php
//Use the specified port or 5555 for sending jobs
$port = $_SERVER['argc'] > 1 ? $_SERVER['argv'][1] : '5555';
$jobN = $_SERVER['argc'] > 2 ? $_SERVER['argv'][2] : '';


$context = new ZMQContext();

//  Socket to send messages on
$sender = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);

//If I want to connect to the server I use this line
$sender->connect("tcp://my-server-address.com:$port");

//If I want to connect to localhost I use this line
//$sender->connect("tcp://localhost:$port");

$sender->send('job-1' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-2' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-3' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-4' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-5' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-6' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-7' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-8' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-9' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
$sender->send('job-10' . ($jobN ? " $jobN" : ''));
echo 'done';
```

The receiver (worker.php)

```
<?php
//Use the specified port or 5556 for getting finished jobs
$port = $_SERVER['argc'] > 1 ? $_SERVER['argv'][1] : '5555';

//  Prepare our context and socket
$context = new ZMQContext();
$receiver = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$receiver->bind("tcp://*:$port");

$count = 1;
while(true) {
    $string = $receiver->recv();
    echo "Received $string $count\n";
    $count += 1;
}
```

If I run the code in my local ("php worker.php" in one terminal and "php sender.php" in another).

I get

```
Received job-1 1
Received job-2 2
Received job-3 3
Received job-4 4
Received job-5 5
Received job-6 6
Received job-7 7
Received job-8 8
Received job-9 9
Received job-10 10
```

but if I use the remote (sender in mu local and receiver in the remote), I get

```
Received job-2 1
Received job-3 2
Received job-4 3
Received job-5 4
Received job-6 5
Received job-7 6
Received job-8 7
Received job-9 8
Received job-10 9
```

Am I doing something wrong??

---

NOTE: I can't put locks on the sender (and SOCKET_REQ locks the execution waiting for the reply). In any way, 0mq is supposed to work without locks.
NOTE: My local is a mac computer and the server is an amazon instance with ubuntu (I don't think that will affect, but I'm writing it just in case it does).

---

EDIT: Just to clarify, I don't want to send data trough internet, I just wanted to test zeromq with high latency when I encountered this problem.

Comment: I have servers in Asia, Europe and the US and I need to share some information between the servers. Do you have a better option??
Also, I wanted to use zeromq as some kind of buffer queue to distribute some jobs and I have more than 50 job servers connected through a network. I'll need to pass messages between those servers and I'm almost certain that 0mq is for that.

Comment: By the way, I'm just testing, I'm not going to throw jobs from my local.

Comment: http://www.zeromq.org/topics:encryption -- 0MQ is not as such secure, any more than its underlying transports are secure. That is, you don't expect TCP to do encryption, and neither does 0MQ. However, **0MQ applications that carry data across the Internet** _do_ need security and there's been quite a lot of talk on how to do this.

Comment: @hakre you were rude here; try to be more polite in the future; if you can't do that don't participate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem, I had different versions of zeromq installed on my local and on the server. If you get the same error, check the versions.

NOTE: Zeromq does work with internet. The only thing (at least in php) is that you need to be sure that the message was sent completely before closing the process. in my test, I sent several times 75000 messages of random sizes (Average size: 1MB) between different computers and I got all the messages as expected.

Comment: yea, i don't know what the commenter above was trying to say. there is almost no technical difference between running zmq across a separate lan or across the internet (so long as your firewalls allow connections to the needed ports). Good job finding this problem!

Comment: Thank you. Let's hope people read the note instead of discarding ZeroMQ.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is what Pieter's documentation calls the "slow joiner".  This is misnamed because it implies it's the subscriber/listener is the root of the problem.  This is not the case.

The problem is most likely on the publisher side.  You are sending your message before the publisher is connected.

How can this be?  zmq_connect or zmq_bind returns so you must be ready.  **No**, you are not.

Apparently the connection/publishing setup is not complete when the connect/bind returns.  The connection is finished some time *after* the function returns.

So how do you solve the problem?  The easy way is to wait.  The problem with this is you don't know how long to wait and the actual time depends on the particular network situation and the hardware involved.

A better way, but more involved, is to set up a local subscriber for your publisher address and repeatedly publish an administrative message which once received lets you know you are up and ready.

Comment: In my case I had different versions of ZeroMQ installed. That was causing the loss in the messages. One important thing is that I was using Pull/Push sockets. I haven't touched ZMQ lately, but from my understanding, the slow joiner with push/pull sockets doesn't loose packages. What it does is affect the load balancing of the messages. If I was using Publisher/Subscriber sockets, the message loss might have been caused by this.

Comment: Found it: The pipeline pattern also exhibits the "slow joiner" syndrome, leading to accusations that PUSH sockets don't load balance properly. If you are using PUSH and PULL, and one of your workers gets way more messages than the others, it's because that PULL socket has joined faster than the others, and grabs a lot of messages before the others manage to connect. If you want proper load-balancing, you probably want to look at the The load-balancing pattern in Chapter 3 - Advanced Request-Reply Patterns. (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#header-15)

Comment: @glenn does this mean that the connection is established after all subscribers are connected? What if i have a very slow subscriber because of a high delay internet connection (4-5sec delay) and i have the loval very fast subscriber. is the connection established after both connected? What happens if the slow subscriber is offline?

Comment: Why when subscriber connect first for some time, but there will still be lost messages?